# How can I count only "TRUE" as a result of count function, and conver 0 for "FALSE" output?

Tags: r, function, count

I fill out matrix with number of count of "Happened", "Cancelled", "Delayed" from list with count function. But the output of frequency comes with False and True, and I only need to pick if it is True outputs.

```
> count(sample.subset[[1]][ ,6]=="Cancelled")
   x freq
TRUE    7

> count(sample.subset[[1]][ ,6]=="Happened")
    x freq
FALSE    7
```

How can I pick freq 7 from TRUE?
Cause the events were actually canceled. not happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TRUE` and `FALSE` are 1 and 0 if treated as numbers. So `TRUE + TRUE = 1 + 1 = 2` and `TRUE + FALSE = 1 + 0 = 1`.

Therefore, replace `count` with `sum` and you will get the number of TRUE.

```
sum(sample.subset[[1]][ ,6]=="Cancelled")
```

Comment: Just to add: if column contains NA values you need either `sum(..., na.rm=TRUE)` or (IMHO better) `sum(... %in% "Cancelled")` (`%in%` never returns `NA`).